# Does Google load balancer support mapping mTLS by DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, client-certificate, google-cloud-http-load-balancer, mtls

I am currently reading about the gloal external application load balancer, which supports:

1. balancing to two cloud run functions
2. supports mTLS

I want to map two domains to the load balancer:

1. domain1.com
2. domain2.com

For each domain i want to map them to a cloud run function, but i want to use two different client certificates (that has two different sets of CA and intermediates). As i understand the mTLS features of the load balancer, you can have a Trust Store where you store your CA and intermediate, to validate the client certificate, but the headers sent to the backend:

1. client_cert_sha256_fingerprint
2. client_cert_serial_number
3. client_cert_uri_sans
4. client_cert_dnsname_sans
5. client_cert_present
6. client_cert_chain_verified

doesn't contain information for me to differentiate between the two sets of CAs and intermediates. Sure i cant configure the serial number and fingerprint, but the client certs is short lived, and all i really want to do is get a header sent to me backend telling me, what pair of CA and intermediate was used. Fx if i could get the Issuer of the client cert in a header, or the validated certificate, so i could unwrap it my self, and check what chain was used. I can't do this, but it got me thinking: i am able to do this:

1. create two Trust configs, and two trust store: store_1 and store_2
2. use store_1 for domain1.com
3. use store_2 for domain2.com

Then i know that when i get a client_cert_chain_verified for Host: domain1.com, it has been verified correctly, and same for domain2.com.

Or do i have to use two load balancers for this?

Comment: is this a two different domain? or it is just one domain and a subdomain? –

Comment: @YvanG. Two different domains

Comment: Why not use the client certificate CN to determine the authorization path?

Comment: @JohnHanley but the CN isn't sent to the upstream, as i understand it

Comment: You can add the header `client_cert_uri_sans` and `client_cert_dnsname_sans` to be sent to the backend. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/mtls

Comment: @JohnHanley i actually knew these was sent to upstream, but i am a bit unsure what those covers. I thought they contained some other stuff where i could see what client cert it was validated. Does there exist an example of how those look? I am not particularity strong when it comes to client certificates.

Comment: Just read the header in the backend to see what is sent. It contents depend on what you put in the client certificate.

Comment: @JohnHanley i am a bit unsure what the content should be. If there is any at all. But I will check when I set the LB up. It is not me who has generated the certs. Thanks!

Comment: Ask the person who created the certificates what values they used. You can also use the tool `openssl` to display the certificates.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this can be done using a single Load Balancer, if you are going to map your domains to a separate cloud run, you can do this by adding a backend service, in a single load balancer you can have multiple backend services. You can follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) on how you can choose cloud run as a backend service of your load balancer.

You can manage your certificate under “Certificate Manager” as you can see on the screenshot[1] below, I added two certificates with different domains. To add these certificates in a single load balancer in frontend configuration make sure you use HTTPS in protocol to have an option on creating or adding certificates.

In my second screenshot[2] below, you will see that the two created certificates (example1 and example2) are on the option. I choose “example” for the first certificate then click "Additional certificates” to place the second certificate which is the “example2” you check this screenshot[3] below.

[1][image]

[2][image][3][image]

Comment: This is true, if we are talking server certificates, but i am referring to client certificates.